# C# Delete from XAML Listbox

Tags: c#, mysql, database, xaml, delete-row

I need some help in c#

[artikel listbox with <ListBox.ItemTemplate>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sVd8.png)
I have 3 Forms (person, lieferant, artikel -> mysql database), in artikel I try to delete a row from a listbox.row...but I get the follow message
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wGj4.png)

The same code in lieferant will done well, but in artikel I have id, name, beschreibung, groesse, farbe, menge, preis in lieferant id, name only:

```
private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbArtikel.SelectedValue == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Keinen Eintrag zum Löschen ausgewählt");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    MessageBoxResult messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Wollen Sie wirklich den Artikel aus der Datenbank löschen?", "Bitte bestätigen Sie den Löschvorgang", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
                    if (messageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        string sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM artikel WHERE id=?";
                        odbcCmd = new OdbcCommand(sqlDelete, odbcCon);
                        odbcCon.Open();
                        odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Int32.Parse(lbArtikel.SelectedValue.ToString()));
                        odbcCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType() + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Datenbankfeheler");
                }
                finally
                {
                    odbcCon.Close();
                    ArtikelShow();
                    odbcCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
```

who can help me? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse the SelectedValue to an Integer. I think you need SelectedItem to get its instance, and from there you can access its ID.

```
lbArtikel.SelectedItem.ID
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm a beginner, can you tell me how to do that, because Im not shure to understand it, please

Comment: You try to parse lbArtikel.SelectedValue to an integer. If you have a look at the value, it should read something like that: {System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: Los Angeles}. That's an object of the string that's in the line you selected. But you want to get your item with ID and other data.

Comment: You need `var id= (lbArtikel.SelectedItem as YourArtikelModel).id`